# Adding taxonomy terms to multiple nodes at once

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I've got thousands of nodes which i can filter down to smaller lists using Views.

I then wish to add multiple taxonomy terms to the subset of nodes as a batch process. [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module gives me the ability to select each node using a tick box but no suitable action to apply to the selected nodes.

Is there any way to tag my selected nodes with taxonomy terms easily or do i need to build a module / Rule action in code to achieve this?

Older versions of Drupal appear to have had such ability: [QEdit](http://drupal.org/project/qedit) and [Views Tagger](http://drupal.org/project/views_tagger) came up whilst searching for a solution.

Thoughts...?

Comment: Looks like the Imager Tagger view in the video at http://www.masteringdrupal.com/screencast/bulk-image-uploading-and-tagging-imagex-and-views-bulk-operations is what I want in Drupal 7.

Comment: If you apply the VBO patch [here][1], you will be able to mass update


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11421/mass-update-of-taxonomy-term-references